# Javascript resource url from config

Tags: javascript, web-config

On a .net MVC3 application, I need to load the Javascript resource URL from a web.config, so that test/dev environments could have a different URL path for a specific javascript resource.

If you know how to do this best, please help :)

Thanks!
Bull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
<%@ Import namespace="System.Web.Configuration" %>

<script src='<%: WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyJavaScriptFile"] %>'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Config Transforms?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can do it. Read put your data on server side to view bad, for example, 
and on client attach to some variable

```
var url = "<# ViewBag["URL"]>";
```